# What are some tools and methods to write automated tests for a Windows custom Credential Provider?

Tags: authentication, dll, windows-10, automated-tests, credential-providers

We do a lot of manual testing on a Windows 10 custom credential provider that uses MFA after inputting the windows password on login. I was wondering what would be some methods, tools, frameworks, etc to do some automated tests for a credential provider? I have been scouring the internet for any information on this and have come up dry so far. Thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?. Apparently I'm looking for the same.

Comment: Any progress so far?